# JsonConvert localized number with decimals in json.net

Tags: c#, formatting, json.net

I'm using `json.net` to serialize and deserialize an object. The only problem is that when I try to deserialize the object, it fails to parse the `double` values it has just created. When serializing, it makes the decimal character `.`, but when it tries to deserialize, it expects `,`

The issue here might be that I'm running the deserialization in an app on a device. And the device might be set to a different localization than the server that's creating the JSON.

So is it possible to force `json.net` to deserialize `double` with `.` as a decimal character, no matter what the localized formatting might be?

**edit** There was a bug on this in the json.net codeplex, but it was the opposite. I tried switching my type from `double` do `decimal`, and now it works perfectly...

**edit2:**

```
class Spot
{
    int Id;
    string Name;
    double Distance;
    double Rating;
}
```

And I guess the default culture is the system culture, right? Which would be norwegian(`nb-NO`)

[Here's the output.](http://ordentligkaffe.no/spotservice/Spots/GetSpotsWithinDistance.ashx?lat=63,43&lon=10,39&distance=10000&skip=0&take=50) And as you can see, I'm sending inn doubles with `,` for latlong values, which are parsed as `double` in the service.

Comment: Could you post the class, how you were deserializing/serializing and what culture your application is running under? That sounds like a bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @James Newton-King: I updated my question with some code samples.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like this might be a bug in Json.NET.

The decimal separator should always be `.` according to the [JSON spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) (see section 2.4).

Having said that, it's possible -- I don't know -- that Json.NET might allow you to override the culture that's used when attempting to deserialise.

Comment: Kind of a non answer